# extracting values from describe() in python

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way we could extract values from describe function in python ?

for an example i have this table

```
basicprofiling = pdf.toPandas().describe()


        product   Bs_type     country   period  table_name
count       200     200       200       200     200
unique      2        1        1         1       2
top       Deposits  Retail  vietnam   daily    animal
freq        100     200     200        200      100
```

lets say i would want to extract and print product count,unique no and total type. 
is this achievable ?

this is what i tried 
basicprofiling.select('prf_product') but it is returning error on str not callable

Comment: 3 people have taken out their time in answering your question. Do you care to select the best answer and/or give feedback/comments if the answer is not good

Answer (score 1):

Describe returns a DataFrame where the summary names are the index, so you can access all the counts (for example) using `loc`, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
data = df.describe()

data.loc['count']
```

And individual values like this:

```
data.loc["count","a"]
```

Comment: much better to put the column withing ```loc``` :   ```data.loc["count","a"]```

Comment: [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) should be avoided

Comment: Didn't know that! Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_frame()` to get a DataFrame from the Series (output of `describe`) and then `.T` to tranaform the Series indices to column names. Then you can simply access the values you want. For example

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
basicprofiling = s.describe().to_frame().T

print (basicprofiling['count'], basicprofiling['unique'])
# 4, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run this line, you will see that 
`print(type(df.describe()))` actually returns a dataframe:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

So you can access values inside like you would a regular dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,4],"b":[2,1],"c":[7,9],"d":[1,3]})
print(df.describe()['a']['count'])
```

The output will be: `2.0`

Comment: It returns a dataframe when your `df` is dataframe to start with, Try using `df = pd.Series({"a":[1,4],"b":[2,1],"c":[7,9],"d":[1,3]})` and then `print`